# MPDF No inserta mi hoja de estilos css

Tags: php, html

Buen día, estoy trabajando con `mpdf` para generar formados pdf a partir de un documento `html` tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
<?php
 require('MPDF57/mpdf.php');
$html='';

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4');
$mpdf->writeHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('prueb.pdf','I');
?>
```

Dentro de la variable `$html` agregue todo mi `html` que quiero que se pase a pdf, ya probé agregando todo desde todo el `html`, a partir del `head` y nada, 
pero los estilos están correctamente designados ya que el mismo cuerpo del documento lo tengo en otro fichero para pruebas y se ve perfectamente.
alguien sabe que podría ser? 
los `php`, `html`, `css` los tengo en ficheros diferentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `css` lo agregas desde instrucción en `php`, no desde el `html`:

```
<?php
$html = $divPrint;

include('MPDF57/mpdf.php'); // including mpdf.php
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('pdf.css'); // la ruta a tu css
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Primero va el `html` en `$html`, después el archivo `mpdf.php`.

Comment: sabes como agregar dos diferentes estilos?
solo me acepta el primero de la manera como me explicaste!

Comment: Intenta crear una nueva pregunta añadiendo código, aquí una posible solución http://stackoverflow.com/a/33902821/4987172